# BigCommerce: How can I tidy up the theme.scss.json file?

Tags: css, bigcommerce

First time working on Big Commerce. I'm tasked with tidying up a clients site in response to Googles Core Vitals.

I noticed that the site's theme.css file has loads of unused styles. Searching the theme directory I noticed these seem to come from a file `theme.scss.json`.

I experimented with deleting the entire file, but nothing happened. The unused styles still remain in my theme.css.

Would anyone know how I can clean this up?

Comment: You would need to actually go into the `assets/scss` folder and try to find the CUSTOM (not bc-native) styles that have been added by third-party developers and figure out how to purge those. Not a fun task :)

Comment: At our agency we put all custom styles into a special folder. Some developers throw their custom styles wherever they feel like it.